# How to add an icon in the product page of WooCommerce ONLY after the price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I added the following code after doing some research online on how to do this, the issue is that, this code adds an icon to both the product page of a product as well as the mini overview of the other products, which isn't what I want, I want to have the icon showing only on all product pages alone.

Seeking some assistance on how to achieve this.

[I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu6Ir.png)

[What I want to remove.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko24L.jpg)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2 );

function prepend_append_icon_to_price( $price, $product ) {

        $price .= '<span style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span> ';

    return $price;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2);

function prepend_append_icon_to_price($price, $product) {
    if (is_product()) {
        $price .= '<span style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span> ';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

You can use `is_product()` [woocommerce conditional tag](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) for check is a single product page

Comment: Thank you for the assist mujuonly so after trying the code you added YES!, it did stop the icon from showing in the homepage. However I noticed a new issue. So apparently while it did work partially I noticed that my sites widgets, like the side bars like : latest products or related products had the icon still appearing. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: You may check if any other hook suites your needs - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/